# Prevent child div from stretching

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```html
<div class="panels">
    <div class="info-panel" id="heatmap-panel">
        <div class="panel-wrapper">
            <div class="panel-header"><h4>Metrics</h4></div>
            <div class="heatmap-layer-switcher">
                <label><input type="checkbox">Population</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="info-panel" id="objects-panel">
        <div class="panel-wrapper">
            <div class="panel-header"><h4>Objects</h4></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```css
.panels {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.info-panel {
    position: relative;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
    background-color: rgba(128,128,128,0.2);
    color: #5b5b5b;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: none;
}

.panel-wrapper {
    margin: 10px;
}

#heatmap-panel {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#objects-panel {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

As a result I have block "Objects" which has normal width when "Metrics" block is hidden, but after "Metrics" becomes visible it stretches the parent .panels div and the "Objects" div to its width.

[image]

**How can I prevent the "Objects" div from being stretched by "Metrics" div and float it to the right of the parent .panels div?**

UPD: I expect the result to be like

[image]

Comment: http://jsbin.com/xefacaze/1/edit I can see the `width` is same.

Comment: @KheemaPandey Thank you for participating. So this is my problem that they both have the same width, however "Objects" div has a shorter content and should be smaller than "Metrics" div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with adding such css to .info-panel

```html
float: right;
clear: both;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/doa0t3rp/

Answer (score 1):

You'd need separate class/id for the "Objects" element because you need to position it differently.

```
.panels {
    width:35%;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.info-panel {
    float:left;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.2);
    color: #5b5b5b;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
.info-panel2 {
    float:right;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.2);
    color: #5b5b5b;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
.panel-wrapper {
    margin: 10px;

}
#heatmap-panel {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#objects-panel {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wdws1p64/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need a bit another positioning. Divs should be both aligned to the right side and they should go vertically one after another as on the example picture. The problem is only about the width of the divs.